# Firebase - Check Password

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a scenario that requires checking an entered password against the user's firebase password before the user does an irreversible task. This is different from creating an account or signing in. How can you check against a firebase password? It doesn't look like there's a `password` property in  `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

**Update:**
The user must verify their password and the Delete button will run a function to check it. If it matches the firebase password, the Delete button will succeed in triggering a pretty modal to pop up.

[image: Password Verification]

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to [re-authenticate the user's credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the user password somewhere if you need to check against it at some point.

Instead of storing it inside your database (which wouldn't be safe) I would personally store it on user's device using UserDefaults so that you can access it easily whenever you need to perform your sensible tasks.

Update:

Another possibility would be using the reauthenticateWithCredential method. If the method return success then, perform your sensitive task. If it fails, ask your user to type the correct password.

As per your request, this is how you would reauthenticate the user using his email & password :

```
// First you get your current user using Auth :

let currentUser = Auth.auth()?.currentUser

// Then you build up your credential using the current user's current email and password :

let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)    

// use the reauthenticate method using the credential :
 currentUser?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }

    // If there is no error, you're good to go

    // ...Do something interesting here

})
```

You can find some more explanation inside the Firebase documentation here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Comment: Can you please provide an example of `reauthenticateWithCredential`. It requires passing in a `credential` argument which I'm not sure how to use.